# Silverlight Accordion control: all collapsed when loaded

Tags: c#, silverlight, accordion, silverlight-toolkit

I'm currently working on a project where I have an Accordion control on the MainPage. It all works just as intended, but there's a small problem that I cannot seem to get my head around.

When I load the page, the first accordion is expanded. Is there any work-around to tell the Accordion control, that all the accordions should be collapsed when first loaded?

Also, I can click to expand the items, but when I click on the same item that I just expanded, it won't collapse again. Anyone know which event I should reach for here?

Thanks in advance.

All the best,

Bo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change the `SelectionMode` property to `ZeroOrOne` the default is `One` which means it will insist on having at least one item open.

Set the `SelectedIndex` property to -1 to hide all items.

Comment: Anthony,

Thanks so much! That was just what I needed :)